# ITextShape Clickable Polygon or path

Tags: c#, itext

Anyone out there able to create clickable annotation that is an irregular shape using iTextSharp.

I know I can create a rectangular one like this

```
  float x1 = 100, x2 = 200, y1 = 150, y2 = 200;

  iTextSharp.text.Rectangle r = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  PdfName pfn = new PdfName(lnk.LinkID.ToString());
  PdfAction ac = new PdfAction(lnk.linkUrl, false);
  PdfAnnotation anno = PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(stamper.Writer, r, pfn, ac);

  int page = 1;
  stamper.AddAnnotation(anno, page);
```

Any way to do that with say a graphics path, I have seen this answer [Draw a GraphicsPath in a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796669/draw-a-graphicspath-in-a-pdf), but that just draws the shape it is not clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret ingredient you are looking for is called **QuadPoints** ;-)

Allow me to explain how QuadPoints are used by showing you the [AddPolygonLink](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/AddPolygonLink) example.

You've already discovered how to construct and draw a path, for instance:

```
canvas.moveTo(36, 700);
canvas.lineTo(72, 760);
canvas.lineTo(144, 720);
canvas.lineTo(72, 730);
canvas.closePathStroke();
```

I am using this code snippet only to show the irregular shape that we'll make clickable.

You already know how to create a clickable link with a rectangular shape:

```
Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(36, 700, 144, 760);
PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
    linkLocation, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
    1, destination);
```

This corresponds with the code snippet you already provided in your question.

Now let's introduce some QuadPoints:

```
PdfArray array = new PdfArray(new int[]{72, 730, 144, 720, 72, 760, 36, 700});
link.put(PdfName.QUADPOINTS, array);
```

According to ISO-32000-1, QuadPoints are:

> An array of 8 × n numbers specifying the coordinates of n quadrilaterals
>   in default user space that comprise the region in which the link should be activated.
>   The coordinates for each quadrilateral are given in the order
>
> ```
> x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4
> ```
>
> specifying the four vertices of the quadrilateral in counterclockwise order.
>   For orientation purposes, such as when applying an underline border style,
>   the bottom of a quadrilateral is the line formed by `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`.
>
> If this entry is not present or the conforming reader does not recognize it,
>   the region specified by the `Rect` entry should be used. `QuadPoints` shall
>   be ignored if any coordinate in the array lies outside the region specified by `Rect`.

Note that I defined the `linkLocation` parameter in such a way that the irregular shape fits inside that rectangle.

**Caveat:** you can try this functionality by testing this example: [link_polygon.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/link_polygon.pdf), but be aware that while this will work when viewing the file in Adobe Reader, this may not work with inferior PDF viewers that did not implement the `QuadPoints` functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I guess not know what its called is what was my stumbling block